# why each game does not provide the option to download only one graphic quality, instead of having to download low, medium, high and ultra graphics?

Tags: performance, assets, distribution

If there is an option like this it will definitely save storage space.

When you download or stream a film there is an option for graphic quality, and we only download that one graphic quality.

Or is there another reason behind it all?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about developing a game. If you are developing a game, please edit the question and highlight the issues you encountered while implementing such a feature, and tell us what you need help with.

Comment: Personally I can’t think of a better stack exchange for this question.

Comment: Many games do indeed package the highest detail textures into a separate optional download, so I'm not sure I'd agree with the premise of the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is because texture size is not really a barring factor for performance. When you say download in the graphics option context, the only thing you would exclude from download is larger size textures, shadow maps, and that’s generally about it. Even high poly models take very little in the way of memory when they are on the disk.

Memory and performance are often confused as one in the same, but in reality larger textures incur very little in the way of performance. In general, the largest performance gains when selecting lower graphics options come from the algorithms used (or rather, *not used*). For example, antialiasing can be very expensive depending on the algorithm selection. Even better examples of new tech are things like super-sampling, real-time ray tracing and reflections. They will literally make your computer hot because they are so taxing on your hardware. Meanwhile, the downloaded bits are only a drop in the bucket.

As far as why they don’t allow you to download them separately, that is a matter of design decision. World Of Warcraft has historically allowed you to play the game even as it downloads because they download the smallest things first. Other games choose not to, typically because when someone changes the graphics settings, they would despise having to wait another half hour to play their AAA game. That, or the fact that games are now designed with multiple platforms in mind make the task both expensive to coordinate and lacking in a decent gain.